# Switchable graphics drivers installation on Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, drivers, intel, amd

Firstly, sorry if there is something unclear in my question but English is not my native language and I will correct the question if needed. Here is my problem:

I have a notebook with ATI RADEON (venus pro) HD 8850M dedicated GPU and intel HD 4400 GPU. I have installed Intel GPU drivers successfully by modifying /etc/lsb-release and using their GUI (Intel(R) Graphics Installer).

However i have had no success installing AMD drivers.
After clean Mint Linux 17 xfce install (no Intel drivers) I downloaded the linux x64 drivers from AMD's website. I have executed the *.run file, some GUI wizard showed up and I tried to install drivers but then I got the message `Your graphics adapter is not supported by this driver. Installation will not proceed.`. Then I downloaded the latest beta version of the driver and tried the same but again I got the message `Your graphics adapter is not supported by this driver....`.

I have searched for the message above and I have read that AMD dropped support for many of their products and that might be the reason I get it. However ATI HD 8850M was released in 2013 so is it possible AMD to have dropped driver support?

Anyway I decided to try another approach. I have used the Synaptic package manage and installed fglrx, fglrx-amdcccle and fglrx-pxpress. Then I rebooted and after reboot I was able to start the Catalyst Control Center. I have used GUI program called "Hardinfo" to check if AMD GPU was running instead and it was running. I have checked also in google chrome `chrome://gpu` to see if hardware acceleration worked and it worked. Everything seemed to be OK.

Next I used CCC to switch graphics to the Integrated Intel GPU and rebooted. It could not boot correctly first time. Mint logo showed up but after it disappeared nothing more happened  except that I could see the screen black with backlight on, heat started to build up rapidly and fans accelerated. I have waited more than 5 minutes to boot after the screen was black but nothing happened.
Next time it started normally and using `hardinfo` I could see that Intel GPU was used. Checked `chrome://gpu` and hardware acceleration worked too.

I have succesfully started Catalyst CC, switched to AMD graphics and rebooted without problems. When I checked what `hardinfo` was saying I saw Intel GPU was used and not AMD (I switched to it before restart). Then I tried to open Catalyst CC but I had no success. I tried to run it using cli as I have successfully done before (`sudo amdcccle`) but I got `command not found`. When I checked `/usr/lib/fglrx` everything was there so I tried to run amdcccle and I got the message that I had no compatible graphics (or something similar)  and i t refused to start up. Synaptic package manage showed that fglrx, fglrx-amdcccle ... were installed so I removed them completely, rebooted and tried to install them again. However I could not start Catalyst again normally. `sudo amdcccle` still results in `command not found and if I run it from`/usr/lib/fglrx` it says i have no compatible device or sth...

I also tried to install the "fglrx-update, fglrx-amdcccle" combo instead but I had the same experience.

The last thing I tried was using Mint Linux's  "Driver Manager" GUI and it shows three options: "xserver-xorg-video-ati" which is the recommended option and "fglrx" and "fglrx-update".

**Is there any way to install both Intel and AMD graphics drivers and be able to switch GPUs when I want? Why I was unable to start Catalyst CC normally after switching to Intel HD 4400 and back? Why `command not found`? Was it removed from the path variable after the reboot and why? Have AMD dropped the support for ATI Radeon HD 8850 and if they have stopped supporting it what could I do?**

Comment: Some very quick Googling revealed this article.  Does this help:  http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1501

Comment: Ewhac, I have done roughly the same (what is described in the article). Didn't you read my post :)? I have installed fglrx and corresponding software but my problem is that I cannot start Catalyst in order to switch graphics.

Comment: @dudelgrincen: Interesting, a question with 5 upvotes (including me), but no answers. Did you find a solution?

Comment: It seems that AMD proprietary drivers quality is not very good. As far as I know open source drivers are recommended instead.

Comment: Open source packages however do not include Catalyst CC alternative. I have not found solution. Maybe there is better driver support for another Linux Distribution (not Debian based). I had also had AMD GPU driver problems on Windows 8 (related to sleep and shutdown). Now I use Windows 7 on this PC without any problems. Maybe I could use the AMD GPU and ignore the problem but Windows seems to be adequate to my needs.

Comment: There is a very well written blog about this [here](http://xpressrazor.wordpress.com/2013/10/08/enable-and-use-open-source-radeon-drivers-in-a-muxless-hybrid-graphics-intelamd-setup/)  If you still run into issues I'll start experimenting on my own laptop.

Comment: hardware support is not distribution-related, so Switching to an other Linux is the last thing I would do in your situation. I myself also had problems with the Intel driver, but other than the one you have, so I cant help you with the problem, I only wanted to say if you like the distribution you are on now, stick with it, underneath the visible changes all Linuxes are basically the same.

Comment: Does this [Gentoo Forum Post](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-909802.html) lead in the right direction?

Comment: Have you tried [omega](http://www.amd.com/en-us/innovations/software-technologies/technologies-gaming/catalyst) catalyst drivers? you just download packages that you need and run `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`